# overflow:hidden ignoring bottom padding

Tags: html, css, xhtml

In the following example, the bottom padding is ignored, and the text flows to the bottom of the element before hiding. What is causing this?

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 100px; padding: 50px;">
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
</div>
```

A view with Firebug (purple is padding, blue is actual content area):

[image: Firebug]

Comment: sorry, but what else should happen? P are block elements and do not float, the div has a fixed height so the P Elements end up overlapping with the padding ...

Comment: Set overflow to scroll, then scroll the content all the way to the bottom. You'll find the bottom padding over there.

Comment: have you found a solution for this? i'm expecting the same problem for the right padding

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS padding overrides overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051411/css-padding-overrides-overflow)

Answer (score 20):

I prefer to use as few `<div>`s as possible.

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
</div>

.container{
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 170px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container:after{
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bgaR9/

naturally in a world without IE < 9

Comment: Please review this answer. It doesn't seem to contribute to the question.

Comment: I don't think so. Have you see the CSS in jsFiddle?

Comment: It contributes just fine. He is just trying to solve problem without adding additional div. I personally think it is a good solution, as there are few here too.

Answer (score 10):

The bottom padding exists but the content pushes the bottom padding down and is not visible because of overflow:hidden. What you can do is place the content in a container like so:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width: 300px; height: 200px; border:1px solid #000; ">
    <div style="overflow:hidden; width:auto; height:140px; border:30px solid #ff0000;">
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can play with the fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/BMZeS/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you're going to get the effect you are looking for without adding a 2nd div.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mxhzf/

(background color added to make it clear what is happening)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">

        <!-- CONTENT HERE -->

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#outer{
     width: 300px;  
     height: 300px; 
    padding: 20px;
}

#inner{
     width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late to the game, but Padding renders internal content the same as the content area (that's one of the ways it's different from a Border or a Margin).

[Learn More About the Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

You'll notice this most clearly if you set background colors or background images to divs with padding. The background color/image extends beyond the content portion and appears inside the padding area.

The solution is to set a margin instead. or a combination of a padding and margin (where there is no bottom padding, but instead a bottom margin of equal height.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 100px; margin:50px;">
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uhg38/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Uhg38/6/

Updating your jsfiddle shows that there is no padding against the containing div.

Answer (score 1):

If your CSS uses  `padding-bottom` and `overflow:hidden` together,it will cause the problem you describe.

The best solution is:

```
<div style="padding: 50px; border:1px solid #000">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 100px;">
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
        <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Click here for live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/liang139163/CRguv/)

Answer (score 1):

Really late answer, but I want to give a really fresh and elegant solution with **CSS**. One could involve `::after` pseudo-elements, but a more sustainable solution is:

```css
    #mydiv p:last-child{
        margin-bottom:50px;
    }
```

assuming the div can have an `id` or a `class` to be identified with. In this solution the last `<p>` element will fill the missing bottom space.

No more nested nodes and fiddling with HTML! Yuppie!

Comment: If you know which element will be the last this is the most elegant solution since it doesn't mess up the markup.

Comment: Wish I could use this, but I don't know which elements will be in my container :/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old now, but I had this issue recently and fixed it by adding an additional inner div which has a margin.

```
.promo {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;    
    padding: 0px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    height: 86px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 7px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.promo .inner p {
    padding 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7xhuF/1/

Answer (score 0):

wrap the content in a div with a clip property!!

check out heldin's answer @ [How can I force overflow: hidden to not use up my padding-right space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071927/how-can-i-force-overflow-hidden-to-not-use-up-my-padding-right-space)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest way was to add an element between the parent and child with

```
overflow:hidden;
height:100%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/va78jsm5/2/

Then I didn't have to worry about matching the height/margin of the middle element.

Answer (score -1):

Overflow has nothing to do with padding. Padding is more like an "internal border" in this case. If you want the overflow to be hidden, you need to change the actual size of your box, and use a bottom-margin of 0px instead. Overflows will still show up in your padding.

aka:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 100px; padding: 50px 50px 0 50px; margin-bottom:0px;">
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
  <p>Hello, this is text.</p>
</div>
```

Padding and Margins always go like this in CSS: top right bottom left (in that order)

If any value is 0px, you can simply use a zero.
like:

```
padding:0;
```

or:

```
padding: 0 10px 0 0;
```

Any value other than zero must be specified with px, em, or pt.