# CSS padding overrides overflow?

Tags: css, overflow, padding

Whats happening here?

```
#agendaTitle{
    margin:0;
    padding:20em 0em 0em 0.75em;
    height:3em;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#ff00ff;
}
```

The top padding is ridiculously high just to demonstrate - with a realistic requirement the div still increases height proportionally.

Surely the `overflow:hidden` means I should just see a block of colour?

Occurs in FF and IE.

Comment: What are you asking?  Try to explain better and post it on JSFiddle please.

Comment: Assuming you're using the default box model (content box) that should display as a 23em high solid block of color (assuming it's on a `div` or other `display: block` element).  padding is added to height and neither of them is 'outside' the box or would be hidden by overflow. If you want padding subtracted from height rather than added to it use `box-sizing: border-box`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the default `content-box` box model on a `display: block` element, `padding` and `height` are added together to determine the total height of the element.  `overflow` only affects things outside the box (outside of height + padding + border).

If you want border and padding subtracted from specified height rather than added, use `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: I am astounded at how many years I have not known padding increases box size. Really I am absolutely amazed. Anyway as most other answers were right, this was the first posted

Comment: @TimHigham Thanks! As a matter of fact, old versions of IE use the `border-box` style box model, where padding and border are subtracted from height rather than added to it like in the default CSS `content-box` box model.  They didn't add support for standards-compliant `content-box` model until IE6, and even then it wasn't default!

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd3UQ/)**

**css**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#agendaTitle{
    margin:0;
    padding:0.75em 0em 0em 0.75em;
    height:3em;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#ff00ff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the height to 3em, so it will show the final height of **( 3em + 20em )**.

And overflow will restrict only for height i.e 3em.