# CSS - overflow:auto is ignoring my padding

Tags: html, css

There are some similar questions that have other problems with overflow and padding (concerning hidden attribute, here's some specific problem with absolute positioning and overflow auto - just to make clear that's not the same question asked already on SO), but I didn't find a solution for my problem there, so here we go ...

My body has a grey border. Inside is my main section with content which should have scrollbars when content doesn't fit (so `overflow:auto`). I omitted the fixed menu bar here (that's the reason for that grey border thing). When the content doesn't overflow, everthing is fine - even when it overflows, text in a paragraph respects the padding, but right to the overflow, there's no padding and the content goes to the right and bottom border.

My CSS looks like this

```
body { background-color: lightgray; color: black; }
#main { padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;  left: 12px;  right: 12px;  bottom: 12px;
}
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-style: hidden; }
td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 4px; }
```

and the html is something like this

```
<section id="main">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit
    in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    a narrow table
  </p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    a wide table
  </p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ok4g78k9/)

What do I have to add to the CSS that there's my padding to the right and to the bottom of the large table (i.e. when the content overflows)?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is answered here :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/19051546/1844764

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS padding overrides overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051411/css-padding-overrides-overflow)

Comment: @MortenRepsdorphHusfeldt - no, it's different, and the answer there doesn't help here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that margins are for move the element inside its container, not for expand it.

You can avoid this situation adding a content `wrapper` and set its `display` to `inline-block`.

```
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
}

#main {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 12px;
}
.wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: hidden;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit
    in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    a narrow table
  </p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    a wide table
  </p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem
      </td>
      <td>
        ipsum
      </td>
      <td>
        dolor
      </td>
      <td>
        sit
      </td>
      <td>
        amet,
      </td>
      <td>
        ...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    </div>
</section>
```

Additional info: if you want padding between the overflown content and the scrollbars, you have to move the padding line from `#main` to `.wrapper` - that was the original intention of the question.

Comment: Hi Adrian, did you test it? It makes the situation worse than before. Text in the paragraph is now without padding, and the overflown part goes to the border on the right and bottom ...

Comment: hi @outofmind, the text paragraph has the padding of the `#main` element, you just have to give it the right padding you want, for example [jsfiddle](//jsfiddle.net/dzwmomLh/)

Comment: Sorry! I didn't update the fiddle, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dzwmomLh/2/) is updated

Comment: Hi Adrian, the padding of the #main element is the wrong place - no padding in #main, but padding in the wrapper does what I want - if you have padding in #main only, you still have content up to the scrollbars without padding. Only drawback of this solution, the text in the paragraph now has the padding relative to the wrapper, not relative to the #main - with the code in my question the paragraph text looked better (with padding without having to scroll)

Comment: So, [this is near what I wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/dzwmomLh/3/) - thanks for your help.

Comment: in the 3 fiddles I see the same behavior (using FF42) - It overflows in X-axis when the table is wider. if it a narrow table it won't. So I'm not getting the real issue here.

Comment: @dippas - the border of the table goes up to scrollbar in Adrian's versions, but in my version there's 20px padding between the table's border and the scrollbar - (also using FF42)

Comment: There's one problem with `inline-block`: the wrapper-div doesn't fill 100% of the available space - the border of a header won't fill the width - any idea how to tweak this last bit? [here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzwmomLh/7/) - `inline-grid` fills the space but ignores the padding - any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you are breaking the second `p` element with a `br`, so you don't let text fill the entire with.

Comment: If you really need to do it or you have a text that is sorter enough to not fill the width you can set `min-width: 100%` to the wrapper.

Comment: `min-width` is a good idea, but 100% means that I always get a horizontal scrollbar, I'd need something like 100%-40px (padding), but `calc(...)` doesn't seem to be supported in this context.