# Cannot fully scroll down in side panel in an html example from w3school

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, panel

I created an example:

[jsfiffle](https://jsfiddle.net/aless80/wcfwLxtx/)

exactly identical to this one in w3schools:

[w3schools sidenav_push](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push)

except that mine has more anchor tags in the side panel.

Why scrolling to the very bottom of the left pane is not possible?

At some point I saw a difference in that behavior when you scroll down using the bar or with the mouse wheel, so please try both. i tried in Chrome and Firefox.

Html:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a>A</a>
  <a>B</a>
  <a>C</a>
  <a>D</a>
  <a>E</a>
  <a>F</a>
  <a>G</a>
  <a>H</a>
  <a>I</a>
  <a>J</a>
  <a>K</a>
  <a>L</a>
  <a>M</a>
  <a>N</a>
  <a>O</a>
  <a>P</a>
  <a>Q</a>
  <a>R</a>
  <a>S</a>
  <a>T</a>
  <a>U</a>
  <a>V</a>
  <a>..</a>
  <a>W</a>
  <a>X</a>
  <a>Y</a>
  <a>Z</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that the `padding-top` property pushes the content down, but overflow only limits to height.
If you want to the padding to compute with the `100%` height, you have to modify the `box-sizing`.

```
.sidenav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer based on: [CSS padding overrides overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051411/css-padding-overrides-overflow)

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wcfwLxtx/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS.

```
.sideNav {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the padding-top. Eliminating it will enable the entire content to be displayed.

Here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/kzpjmmf2/

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you just need to reduce the padding

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

here is a working example

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXXaKN