# CSS: Get child element to respect parent's padding-bottom

Tags: html, css

I have an element with height, padding, and overflow:hidden. Its child element respects the top and side paddings, but it overlaps into the parent's padding-bottom. How do I prevent this?

http://jsfiddle.net/va78jsm5/

```
#parent{
    background:yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:25px;
}
```

```
<div id = "parent">
  <div id = "child">  
      text text text text text text ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: in response to the suggestion that this is the same as [overflow:hidden ignoring bottom padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981811/overflowhidden-ignoring-bottom-padding/33163094#33163094), it's not. The final answer to my question is so much more elegant than any of the answers to that other question because my setup is different: I only have one child element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overflow:hidden ignoring bottom padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981811/overflowhidden-ignoring-bottom-padding)

Comment: Remove height of parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `height` and `overflow` to the `#child`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/va78jsm5/1/)

```
#child{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one parent div like this

```
<div class="test">
<div id = "parent">
  <div id = "child">  
      text  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Add this css

```
.test{
    width:100px;
    padding:25px;
     background:yellow;
}
#parent{
   height:100px;
    overflow:auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this -

```
#child {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
#parent{
  background:yellow;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  padding:25px;
}

#child {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id = "parent">
  <div id = "child">  
      text  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </div>
</div>

<br/>
<div>
    There should also be padding on the bottom of the yellow square.
</div>
```