# Vertically cut off long text

Tags: html, css

The last visible text line should fit inside 20px padding ... or if not: be cut off completely.

The problem is that the h3 will has always various text length. Therefore I don't know how much I have to cut away.

Right now the text ignores the padding and stays close to the bottom.

How can I do this? 
The box has to keep 100px height.

```
.box {
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
background: antiquewhite;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 20px;}
```

h3 {    margin: 0;}

```
<div class="box"><h3>Various</h3>Loremipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overflow:hidden ignoring bottom padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981811/overflowhidden-ignoring-bottom-padding)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an absolutely positioned empty DIV as a a child DIV at the bottom of the parent, having the same background color as the parent:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: antiquewhite;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 12px;
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> Loremipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
  <div class="x"></div>
</div>
```

(Adjust the height of the child div as needed and note that the parent needs to have `position: relative`)