# Padding Bottom not Working on Forefox,Safari,IE11 Browsers

Tags: html, css, padding

I set some top and bottom padding for parent. and parent direct child does not have height and overflow-y auto. In this case, when I scroll to bottom, child does not have its parent bottom spacing. In chrome, bottom padding spacing working fine. but other browsers had this issue.

```css
body,html
{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   margin:0
}
.parent
{
    padding:30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
   <div>
Where does it come from?

Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your html and css code

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981811/overflowhidden-ignoring-bottom-padding?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071927/how-can-i-force-overflow-hidden-to-not-use-up-my-padding-right-space?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981811/overflowhidden-ignoring-bottom-padding

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051411/css-padding-overrides-overflow?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: first google it. do yourself. then if you don't get that then you will post the code

Comment: @TemaniAfif I saw your comments url. but there is no answer relevent to this question. the answer is firefox,safari,IE has a bug to applying padding-bottom. To solve this issue,we put padding-bottom for last child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is Forefox,Safari,IE11 browsers has a bug on padding-bottom.
To Solve this Issue we will give padding-bottom for last-child.