# CSS Overflow Hidden With Grid Layout

Tags: css, grid

Stackblitz Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lhtjgj?file=src/app/app.component.html

How do I add `row-gap` to provide spacing between each of these "boxed" elements within the `*ngFor` loop?

I do not want to use margin-top because that will add extra padding to the top of the first "boxed" element (same goes for margin-bottom with the last "boxed" element).

I tried to add a `display: grid` to the 'wrapper' `div`, but then `overflow: hidden` gets "ignored".

```css
.box{
  border: .1vw solid;
  padding: 3vw;
}

.label{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let x of documents">
  <div class="box">
      <div class="label">
        Some ridiculously long text entered by the user
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll want to put your code directly into your post, so people can run it from here. Edit the post and hit Ctrl-M, and how to do it should be obvious to you.

Comment: Didn't realize that was an option. Thanks.

Comment: Sure enough. Once they put that in place a few years ago, it got very popular very fast. Makes it easier on all of us.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the grid to your content container if you want a gap between the .iconandlabelcontainer .

Then it's just adding row-gap to your parent container.

```
  requireddocumentsname {
    font-family: var(--pcwidefontnormal2);
    font-size: 5vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: var(--pcblue);
}

.iconandlabelcontainer{
    height: min-content;
    border: .1vw solid blue;
    font-size: 5vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3vw;
  
}

.iconandlabel{
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    width: 400px;
   
}

.content{
    padding: 3vw;
    display: grid;
    row-gap: 30px;
    justify-content:center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: If you do just that, that is my problem, I created a Stackblitz in my question to demonstrate. if you add `display:grid` to content, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to add that CSS to the stackblitz, and doesn't like it, but also updated the stackblitz to be more straightforward and I just want to call out that "content" is the parent div. I don't know that I follow exactly, do you mind forking it off and adding what you are aiming for?

Comment: here the snippet,sorry...I simply missed to save it to the url....bummer [follow me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tdxsvb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: I tried similar to this, but if you notice the padding is now being disrespected on the right. It's been bugging me for hours now.

Comment: Yeah, this issue has been discussed in this thread How can I force overflow: hidden to not use up my padding-right space
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071927/how-can-i-force-overflow-hidden-to-not-use-up-my-padding-right-space)

Comment: Geez, that was 11 years ago, and still no better solution. I have even tried wrapping it in a second `div`, but for some reason that then causes the boxes to go off the viewport again. I have tried about every CSS trick with out using pseudo classes or margin-top/bottom I get nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `row-gap` then add `grid-template-rows` too.

thats is,

```
grid-template-rows:auto auto;
row-gap:3vw;
display: grid;
```

Similarly,

if you are using `column-gap` then add `grid-template-rows` too.

thats is,

```
grid-template-columns:auto auto;
column-gap:3vw;
display: grid;
```

This will example to worked

```
.content[_ngcontent-oux-c40] {
    padding: 3vw;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    row-gap: 3vw;
    display: grid;
}
```

result:

[image]

The whole screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you try this?

Comment: I created an editable stackblitz that can be used, that doesn't work and a side note for this simple example, grid-template-rows has absolutely no impact, as I am using the "default" grid-template-row structure, which is to repeat and create a new row for each element in the grid.

Comment: Right, the gap is respected, but the rest of the box now goes off the viewport, I don't want the box to stretch after adding display grid.

Comment: Are you want each box element having gap then add the style to `.container[_ngcontent-mhn-c40]`

Comment: I want the boxes to stay the same and only have space in-between each one.

Comment: Hi   `grid-row-gap` makes gap between each row and `grid-column-gap` makes gap between column .

Comment: Can you go [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid-row-gap) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Grid is probably the best way to go, but FYI, you can solve the problem you describe with margins this way:

```
.box{
  border: .1vw solid;
  padding: 3vw;
  margin-top: 3vw;
}

.box:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Similarly, you can use the `:last-child` pseudocode to exclude the last box from a `margin-bottom` setting.